# No response for jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

I am trying to implement autocomplete feature to search product name from database using spring and hibernate. When i type in textbox the request is sent. But i don't get any response.When i debug Controller, productName holds the correct textbox value.When i debug DAO, productName holds "productName" as value.Where i am doing wrong.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getTags", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Product> getTags(@RequestParam String productName) {
List<Product> productResults = productService.getProductByNameForTag("productName");
            return productResults;
            }
```

**ProductDAOImpl**

```
public List<Product> getProductByNameForTag(String productName) {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery
                    ("select p from Product p where p.productName =:productName")
                    .setParameter("productName", productName).list();
        }
```

**Script/JSP**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#productName').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTags',
            paramName: "productName",
            delimiter: ",",
           transformResult: function(response) {

            return {        
              suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

                  return { value: item.productName, data: item.id };
               })
             };
           }
         });
      });

<div>
<form id="searchForm" action="searchproduct.json" > 
    Product Name: <input type="text" name="productName" value="${product.productName}"
                                             id="productName"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed the productName as string in the getProductByNameForTag method. This is the working code.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getTags", method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public @ResponseBody List<Product> getTags(Map model,
                    @RequestParam ("productName") String productName) {

            List<Product> productResults = productService.getProductByNameForTag(productName);
            return productResults;
            }
```